# References on regular subobjects

Tags: reference-request, ct.category-theory

There is an extensive literature on the properties of the posets of subobjects. For example, volume I of Borceaux' "Handbook of Categorical Algebra".

Is there however a reference for regular, extremal, or strong subobjects?

Comment: Well, to the extent that you're often studying this poset in a topos, there's no difference between subobjects and regular subobjects!

Comment: @KevinCarlson from that particular perspective - already in quasitoposes, this difference becomes crucial. Quasitoposes appear naturally and are important in topos theory, categories of objects separated with respect to a coverage (or, more generally, with respect to a Lawvere-Tierney operator on the subobject classifier) being one of their important examples.

Comment: @მამუკაჯიბლაძე ... which means that references on quasitoposes, such as Wyler's *Quasitopoi* or section A2.6 of *Sketches of an Elephant*, contain a certain amount of information about regular, extremal, and strong subobjects (which all three coincide in a quasitopos).